# In Django, how to properly access through a proxy model to related proxy models

Tags: django, django-models

I wanted to override the get_absolute_url method in the Django User and Group models from the auth app.

My first idea was to define a proxy model, but then I noticed that the elements in `usuario.groups` were instances of `Group` instead of `Grupo` and it also happened the same in the `grupo.user_set` case. So I expanded the proxy models a bit

```
class Usuario(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('ver_usuario', [self.id])

    @property
    def grupos(self):
        return Grupo.objects.filter(user=self.pk)

    @grupos.setter
    def grupos(self, valor):
        self.groups = valor


class Grupo(Group):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('ver_grupo', [self.id])

    @property
    def usuarios(self):
        return Usuario.objects.filter(groups=self.pk)

    @usuarios.setter
    def usuarios(self, valor):
        self.user_set = valor
```

But then I saw that the `RelatedManager` methods `grupo.usuarios.create(username='test_usuario')` will create the user but it won't associate it with the group and this happens because `grupo.user_set` is a `ManyRelatedManager` and `grupo.usuarios` is a `QuerySet`. So maybe creating a special `ManyRelatedManager`... but at this point I feel that this is growing unnecesarilly complex.

Since I want to replace `get_absolute_url` I'll just use the `url` tag in the templates. But I wonder, if I wanted to add other methods, how should I do it?

Comment: Damn, naw, it's really bad idea to write code in your native language. You seem pretty proficient with english, so it is really a good practice to keep your code in todays lingua franca.

Comment: Well, this project is meant to be local and to only be used on an spanish environment, and reviewed by spanish people so I think that it will be desirable to use spanish names for this. In the example, I would have translated the variable names in the code example, but it seemed pretty simple to know what they meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `get_absolute_url` on a per installation basis by using the [ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERIDES](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#absolute-url-overrides) setting.

Comment: It works for the User, but Group doesn't have the get_absolute_url method do it is not able to override it.